# AngularJS with CORS and custom headers

Tags: http, angularjs, cors

I am using Angular $HTTP to make a CORS request to a remote API service (SmartyStreets.com).  I have set the defaults as is well-documented.

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}])
```

When I make a plain request with no custom headers everything works as expected.

```
// This works as expected
$http({method: 'get', url: $scope.addr.url, headers: {}})
```

However, I need to now set some additional custom headers.  But setting the custom headers breaks the CORS request.

```
// this results in the browser 404 error:
// No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
$http({method: 'get', url: $scope.addr.url, 
headers: {'x-standardize-only': 'true', 'x-  include-invalid': 'true'}})
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple days now...stuck.  Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you!!

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Using 1.2.6 - latest stable release.

Comment: In further troubleshooting, when setting the custom headers, I noticed in Chrome that angular is setting "Access-Control-Request-Headers" when I try to add in custom headers with CORS enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server needs to correctly respond to the OPTIONS request that the browser will make on your behalf to determine if the CORS request is valid. It needs to contain an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header with the right info in it. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: I don't control the server side.  Web service does respond with the correct headers though:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers does not accept a wildcard. The web service is implemented incorrectly.

Comment: Hmmm...if I call the web service without trying to customize the request headers it works successfully.  This is after configuring the default $httpProvider to useXDomain.

Comment: Correct--the server is responding with the wrong ACAH header. You should get them to fix that, because there's no way for it ever to work with the wildcard they have in the response currently.