# Angular resource how to keep ajax header and enable cors at the same time

Tags: ajax, angularjs, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

In my ng-resource files, I enable the ajax header:

```
var app = angular.module('custom_resource', ['ngResource'])

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    //enable XMLHttpRequest, to indicate it's ajax request
    //Note: this disables CORS
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}])

app.factory('Article', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/article/api/:articleId', {articleId: '@_id'}, {
        update: {method: 'PUT'},
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    })
}])
```

So that I can separate ajax and non-ajax request and response accordingly (to send json data like `res.json(data)`, or to send the entire html page like `res.render('a.html')`

for example, in my error handler, I need to decide to render error.html page or to just send a error message:

```
exports.finalHandler = function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500)
    var errorMessage = helper.isProduction() ? '' : (err.message || 'unknown error')

    if (req.xhr) {
        res.json({message: errorMessage})
    }
    else {
        res.render(dir.error + '/error_page.ejs')
    }
}
```

But now I need to do CORS request to other sites. Is it possible to do CORS request while keeping the ajax header? or other ways I can identify ajax and non-ajax request from server?

In case my question is not clear, heres a relevant article about angular and CORS 
http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/

Basically, we need to delete xhr header to enable cors for other server, but I need the header for my own server

EDIT 2:

today I tried integrating google map and I got this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Singapore&sensor=false. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Setting custom headers on XHR requests triggers a preflight request.

So, it doesn't disable CORS but your server is most likely not handling the preflight request.

Inspired from this post: https://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working

The solution should be to use the `cors` module and add the following to your node.js code before your routes:

```
var corsOptions = {
    origin: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST'],
    allowedHeaders: ['X-Requested-With','Content-Type', 'Authorization']
};

app.options('*', cors(corsOptions)); //You may also be just fine with the default options
```

You can read more at: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: is that code in server or client? I want to connect other server, which is not mine

Comment: That code is on the server. If you are working with another server, this means that they are not handling options/preflight request properly. Similar/More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786405/angularjs-with-cors-and-custom-headers This issue is also why AngularJS removed "X-Requested-With" by default. https://goo.gl/Uxyjlh

Comment: The second solution at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945118/detecting-ajax-requests-on-nodejs-with-express could be one way to do it. If that doesn't work, a terrible but working way would be to add a variable to the body to indicate ajax requests. But the best option would be to contact the other sites and ask them to fix it.

Comment: Other options is you unable to use CORS is to use JSONP.

Comment: it's not up to me to decide whether to use jsonp or cors. it's the remote server that requires CORS. but my nodejs server requires the xhr header to distinguish ajax/non-ajax request

Answer (score 0):

you may try to use [cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: this is not what i want. I dont need to enable cors on my server. The other website already has CORS support.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 solutions that come to my mind:
1. Ask site's admin to enable *x-requested-with* header in CORS.
2. Use proxy server.
3. Send request without *x-requested-with* header.

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) should make it clear how CORS works and how to make CORS requests.
Particularly "Simple requests" section and "Access-Control" section, especially access-control-allow-headers description is important in this case.

As it says: for simple requests *access-control-allow-origin* is enough. However if the request includes custom header (a header which is not included by default, such as *x-requested-with* header), the preflight request is triggered, and server's response to this request should enable this custom header in *access-control-allow-headers* by setting its value to either "*" or to the name of a custom header (*x-requested-with*).

Hope it makes it a little bit clearer.

Comment: The remote site allows CORS. But if I set ` $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';` on my client. then it's not working

Comment: Despite CORS enabled on the remote server, it needs to set a list of custom headers enabled in CORS requests, or specify that it allows all headers. If the header you're trying to set (in this case "X-Requested-With"), than request won't work. CORS are generally painful to deal with as I have recently found out in my project :)

Comment: Then is there other ways to remove the xhr header, but still able to distinguish ajax/non-ajax request on my node.js server?

Comment: Do you need to send the same request to the remote server and to your server? If you can send the request with this header to your server, and send the request without this header to remote site than it would work. If this is not the case, than you may try to distinguish ajax vs non-ajax request with User-Agent header. If User-Agent will contain Mozilla, or Chrome, or other browser name, than it is most likely an ajax call, if not its normal request.

Comment: Can you provide more details (preferably with some code)? How can I send request without header to one server and with header to another?

Comment: is setting User-Agent a standard approach? I think xhr is the standard indicator for ajax/non-ajax

Comment: @OMGPOP I've updated my answer with an article. It should clear the issue. Sorry for the chaos, organizing statements in a clear and understandable way is something I need to practice a lot :)

Comment: @OMGPOP: Did you read an article I've linked in my answer? It explains why this error occurs. The solution is not including x-requested-with in calls to external servers beyond your control.

Comment: yes, but I use httpProvider, which is a singleton object that manages all http requests

Comment: @OMGPOP then use $httpProvider to set up default configuration for $http requests (default = without x-requested-with header), and append this header for each $http request to your server, while not do so for each $http to external service. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

First, to address you primary concern *is it possible to do CORS request while keeping the ajax header?*: the answer is **YES**, provided the sites you are accessing allow requests from you or any other external clients at all.

You wrote:

```
//Note: this disables CORS
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

But I don't understand what you mean by, it "*disables CORS*". The `X-Requested-With` header is not a standard header, and the known effect of adding a non-standard header to a request (made from a browser) is the triggering of a pre-flight request [[3](https://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working)].

If the other sites you are interested in would set their servers to refuse processing of requests that do not originate from their own domain, then whether you set that header or not, your request should fail.

It seems everything is working fine for you, for requests sent to you own server. Otherwise you can solve the problem by appending the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header in your server responses as follows:

1. if you need to allow requests from specific domains

   `response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "one-host-domain, your-host-domain, some-other-host-domain"); // second argument is a comma-delimited list of allowed domains`

   (It may be better for you to actually check the request object for the origin, and if it's permitted based on presence in a pre-determined list, then send back the exact same origin).
2. If you need to permit all requests regardless of its origin

   `response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

That should do, and I hope it clears your doubts for you.

More info on handling CORS when using AJAX: [0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), [1](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) & [2](https://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working).

---

### EDIT

Following exchanges in the comment, I add the following points to support this answer further.

As it is today, the only side that needs disabling/enabling CORS in the client-server system is the server. All modern browsers allow cross origin requests by default and you don't need to do anything additional to support that capability. I understood that you're adding a custom header to distinguish AJAX requests from the rest?? AFAIK, that header changes nothing about how requests are made by browsers.

Here is how all cross-origin requests are handled by browsers today: for all request *methods* (but usually with the exception of **GET**), browsers send a pre-flight request with the **OPTION** method. If the destination server allows it, the actual request is then sent, otherwise the request fails. In the case where the servers, responds with a refusal there's nothing you nor whatever library you use can do about it. This is the fact from my own experience.

Comment: Please refer to this article on how to enable cors in angular. http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/

Comment: @OMGPOP, CORS is enabled by default on all modern browsers. You don't need angular to leverage that functionality.

Comment: Even with xhr header? I updated my question at the end.

Comment: CORS is enabled, however requests still could be blocked sometimes if you append a custom header.

Comment: @Buyuk this is odd. can you explain the workaround to enable cors by deleting xhr header?

Comment: @OMGPOP, did you actually try something and got a different result from what I suggested. These things are actually easy to check, FYI.

Comment: @Buyuk, where is the request being blocked? The browser will not block a request if the destination server is ready to accept and process it.

Comment: @IgweKalu If server response doesn't include access-control-allow-header="x-requested-with" than the request should fail after preflight OPTION request.

Comment: @Buyuk, first let's be clear that **access-control-allow-header** is not a standard header. A request should never fail because of that.

Comment: @IgweKalu When you perform an ajax CORS call, first what browser does is send an OPTION request to check the server's response. If CORS is enabled, the response to this request should contain extra headers: access-control-allow-origin and -allow-headers. First one tells the browser which origins are allowed. Second lists custom headers allowed. If access-control-allow-headers is set to "*" or to the name of custom header included in request, than the browser will send the original request and server should respond to it correctly. Otherwise request will never be sent.

Comment: at least that was the case with the CORS requests in my project. I needed to set up this headers in order to get my ajax code working.

Comment: @Buyuk, a response with **access-control-allow-origin** is enough to allow/disallow CORS.

Comment: @IgweKalu Yes it is enough to enable CORS. But enabling CORS alone doesn't enable custom headers in such requests.

Comment: @Buyuk, what does it mean to "*enable custom headers*"? It seems to me you're creating hoops for yourself just so you have a chance to make a jump. But if that works for you, then it's fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83659/discussion-between-buyuk-and-igwe-kalu).